# SQL entries only shown on DataGridSet

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I have developed a winforms application with an SQL database in C#. Once I enter the data into the forms and press the display button it is displayed on the datagridview, but once I restart the application the data does not show up on the grid.

This is the code to add new data.

```
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "")
        {
            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\shenal.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[user] (Id,username,password) values(@id,@name,@state)", con);
           // cmd.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[user] (Id,username,password) values(@id,@name,@state)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", textBox3.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
        }
```

And this is the code to retrieve it.

```
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\shenal.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [dbo].[user]", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Click on the database in the solution explorer and make sure that copy to output directory is set to something other than always copy. Pretty sure your template (database in your solution folder) is overwriting the copy in your bin folder ever time you run the code.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks man